# Make a shell pipeline started from subprocess.Popen fail if the left-hand side of a pipe fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell, subprocess

Im running a bash command with subprocess.popen in python:

```
cmd = "bwa-mem2/bwa-mem2 mem -R \'@RG\\tID:2064-01\\tSM:2064-01\\tLB:2064-01\\tPL:ILLUMINA\\tPU:2064-01\' reference_genome/human_g1k_v37.fasta BHYHT7CCXY.RJ-1967-987-02.2_1.fastq BHYHT7CCXY.RJ-1967-987-02.2_2.fastq -t 14 | samtools view -bS -o dna_seq/aligned/2064-01/2064-01.6.bam -"

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True)
```

The problem is that I get returncode 0 even if the first command fails.
I have googled and found out about pipefail and it seems that this is what I should use.

However, I don't understand where to write it. I have tried:

```
"set -o pipefail && bwa-mem2/bwa-mem2 mem -R \'@RG\\tID:2064-01\\tSM:2064-01\\tLB:2064-01\\tPL:ILLUMINA\\tPU:2064-01\' reference_genome/human_g1k_v37.fasta BHYHT7CCXY.RJ-1967-987-02.2_1.fastq BHYHT7CCXY.RJ-1967-987-02.2_2.fastq -t 14 | samtools view -bS -o dna_seq/aligned/2064-01/2064-01.6.bam -"
```

which gives: **/bin/sh: 1: set: Illegal option -o pipefail**

any ideas how I should incorporate this?

**Edit:**

I'm not sure if it is correct to edit my answer when responding to an answer? there was not enough characters to respond in a comment:/

Anyway,
I tried your second approach without `shell=True` @Charles Duffy.

(cmd_1 and cmd_2 are equal to what you wrote in your solution)

This is the code I use:

```
try:
        
   p1 = Popen(shlex.split(cmd_1), stdout=PIPE)
   p2 = Popen(shlex.split(cmd_2), stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, text=True)
   p1.stdout.close()
   output, error = p2.communicate()
   p1.wait()    
    
   rc_1 = p1.poll()
   rc_2 = p2.poll()
   print("rc_1:", rc_1)
   print("rc_2:", rc_2)

   if rc_1 == 0 and rc_2 == 0:
       self.log_to_file("DEBUG", "# Process ended with returncode = 0")
       if text: self.log_to_file("INFO", f"{text} succesfully 
            
   else:
       print("Raise exception")
       raise Exception(f"stdout: {output} stderr: {error}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e} in misc.run_command()")
    self.log_to_file("ERROR", f"# Process ended with returncode != 0, {e}")
```

this is the result i get when deliberately causing an error by renaming one file:

```
[E::main_mem] failed to open file `/home/jonas/BASE/dna_seq/reads/2064-01/test_BHYHT7CCXY.RJ-1967-987-02.2_2.fastq.gz'.
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
rc_1: -6
rc_2: 0
Raise exception
Error: stdout:  stderr: None in misc.run_command()
 ERROR: # Process ended with returncode != 0, stdout:  stderr: None
```

It seems to capture the faulty returncode.

But why is `stdout` empty and `stderr= None`?
How can I capture the output to have it logged to a logger both when the process is successful and when it fails?

Comment: You have to force your shell to be **bash**, not `sh`, for `pipefail` to be an available option.

Comment: Or, better, stop using any shell at all and just have two separate `Popen` objects, one for each side of the pipeline, both with `shell=False`.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure the original title asking for the "right" return code was appropriate. Sometimes the default shell behavior _is_ more "right" than the `pipefail` behavior -- for example, think of how `curl ... | head` has a nonzero exit status whenever `head` stops reading before `curl` is done writing, causing an EPIPE, thus forcing the left-hand side of the pipeline to have a failed exit status even when everything went perfectly.

Comment: ofc you are absolutely right! thx:)

Answer (score 4):

## First, With A Shell

Instead of letting `shell=True` specify `sh` by default, specify `bash` explicitly to ensure that `pipefail` is an available feature:

```py
shell_script = r'''
set -o pipefail || exit
bwa-mem2/bwa-mem2 mem \
  -R '@RG\tID:2064-01\tSM:2064-01\tLB:2064-01\tPL:ILLUMINA\tPU:2064-01' \
  reference_genome/human_g1k_v37.fasta \
  BHYHT7CCXY.RJ-1967-987-02.2_1.fastq \
  BHYHT7CCXY.RJ-1967-987-02.2_2.fastq \
  -t 14 \
  | samtools view -bS \
    -o dna_seq/aligned/2064-01/2064-01.6.bam -
'''

process = subprocess.Popen(["bash", "-c", shell_script],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           text=True)
```

This *works*, but it's not the best available option.

---

## Second, With No Shell At All

```py
p1 = subprocess.Popen(
  ['bwa-mem2/bwa-mem2', 'mem',
   '-R', r'@RG\tID:2064-01\tSM:2064-01\tLB:2064-01\tPL:ILLUMINA\tPU:2064-01',
   'reference_genome/human_g1k_v37.fasta',
   'BHYHT7CCXY.RJ-1967-987-02.2_1.fastq',
   'BHYHT7CCXY.RJ-1967-987-02.2_2.fastq', '-t', '14'],
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(
  ['samtools', 'view', '-bS',
   '-o', 'dna_seq/aligned/2064-01/2064-01.6.bam', '-'],
  stdin=p1.stdout,
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
  stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
  text=True)
p1.stdout.close()
output, _ = p2.communicate() # let p2 finish running
p1.wait()                    # ensure p1 has properly exited

print(f'bwa-mem2 exited with status {p1.returncode}')
print(f'samtools exited with status {p2.returncode}')
```

...which lets you check `p1.returncode` and `p2.returncode` separately.

Comment: Thank you soo much for you helpful answers! I will try this and come back with my results!:)

Comment: btw...when you use p1.stdout as stdin for p2, how does that work? is p1 and p2 running simultaneously and p1 forwards its output to p2 as time goes on?

and why do you use p1.stdout.close()? what happens if you don't use that?

and how does .communicate() work? does that communicate with popen continously or just one time when its done? and why p1.wait() but not p2.wait?

sorry for a lot of questions but I would really like to understand all of this:)

Comment: Yes, they run simultaneously -- that's how shell pipelines work too! Closing the Python process's copy of `p1.stdout` makes sure that once p1 closes its side, p2 sees the EOF, because no other copies of the file descriptor are still around elsewhere.

Comment: With respect to only needing to call `p1.wait()`, that's because `wait()` is implied by `communicate()`. There's a risk, if we only call `p2.communicate()` but not `p1.wait()`, that Python won't have received p1's exit status yet and so won't have set the `returncode` property. When everything is working right the interpreter also fills that in if it gets a `SIGCHILD` from the operating system informing it that a program it started exited, but "explicit is better than implicit" holds in lots of places, and this is arguably one of them -- signal delivery isn't always 100% reliable.

Comment: @biomedswe, I didn't see until just now that you'd edited the question. In general, follow-up belongs in comments to an answer if it's about something that makes the answer unusable; or in a completely new question, if you solved your first problem but have a new and different issue.

Comment: @biomedswe, ...that said, stderr is None _because we don't have `stderr=PIPE` set anywhere_. If you want to capture the first program's stderr, honestly, that's hard enough to implement without triggering a deadlock that it belongs in its own separate question (the easiest way is to have a separate Python thread capturing it); for the second program's stderr, though, it should be as simple as just adjusting the `stderr=` argument for `p2`.

Comment: thx for clarifying that for me:)

ah, my bad, I saw that I forwarded stderr to stdotu with `stderr=STDOUT`. 
Yes thats what I thougt, have seen many other threads about the deadlocks:) so, in this situation, the first option witg set -o pipefail might be better? will that catch the stderr without deadlocks if I set `stderr=PIPE`? or how do you mean with a separate thread? that the first command should finnish its output and then I run the second afterwards?